# Numbered two-column table in apa6 in a portrait page

Tags: tables, two-column, apa6

I'm writing a paper using apa6 class and I'd like to have a table as wide as two columns in portrait mode. But I also want this table to be numerated.
I've found this in the apa6 manual:

"When an image or table is too wide for a single column, use a double-column float, noted with an asterisk after the float environment designation (see the LaTeX book)"

So I did this:

```
\documentclass[jou,draftfirst,floatsintext]{apa6}  
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Blah & Blah Blah & Blah   & Blah & Blah\\
    \hline
    Blah & Some more text and more Blah Blah  & Blah  & Blah & Blah\\ 
    Blah & Blah Blah BlahBlahBlahBlah  & Blah  & Blah & Blah\\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
      \vspace*{2em}
     \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
     {\small
     \textit{Note.}Some notes.
     }
     \end{tablenotes}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

But then my table doesn't have "Table number" on its top. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a full compilable code. With \documentclass{} and so on (but as short as possible). Are you talkin about capitons? You should insert a \caption{Table number} then.

Comment: Well, I feel stupid, it was only because of \caption{}

Comment: It seems that with less than 10 reputation I can't answer my own question for 8 hours after asking (and "solve" it). If @LaRiFaRi or someone else wants to answer, I'll solve the question sooner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the caption command. You can use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
,jou
,draftfirst
,floatsintext
]{apa6}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \caption{Caption}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \begin{tabular}{lllll}
            \toprule
            Blah & Blah Blah & Blah & Blah & Blah\\
            \midrule
            Blah & Some more text and more Blah Blah  & Blah  & Blah & Blah\\ 
            Blah & Blah Blah BlahBlahBlahBlah  & Blah  & Blah & Blah\\ 
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
            \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
            \small
            \item \textit{Notes:} Some notes.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table*}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: you may put your \vspace over the note again. Don't know, what's going wrong there. Maybe I will do some research tomorrow.